# Have to click two or more times OOTB "Go back on previous page" button in browsers to navigate one page back

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new in react and react-route. I have a list of result or detail page of result and when I would like to navigate to previous page I have to click two or more times on back OOTB "Go back" browser button. Could you help me with this issue, please?

App

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import MainPage from '../pages/MainPage';
import SearchResult from '../components/searchResult/SearchResult';
import ResultDetails from '../components/resultDetails/ResultDetails';
import Header from './header/Header';
import history from '../history';


const App = () => {
    return (
      <div className="ui container">
        <Router history={history}>
          <div>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' component={MainPage} /> 
              <Fragment>
              <Header />
              <Route exact path="/results/:id" component={SearchResult} />
              <Route exact path="/details/:id"  component={ResultDetails} />
              </Fragment>        
            </Switch>

          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  };

  export default App;
```

Main Index

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';

import App from './components/App';
import reducers from './reducers';

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
    reducers,
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(reduxThunk)),
    );

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.querySelector('#root')
  );
```

History

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'; 

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

Comment: Can you show us how you're linking to the pages? Does the tab history have excess routes? You might be redirecting twice due to some event propagation issue or something similar

Comment: All is done in action import discogs from '../apis/discogs';
import history from '../history';
import { FETCH_POSTS, SEARCH_ARTIST, FETCH_ARTIST_DETAILS, CLEAN_ARTIST_DETAILS } from './types';

export const fetchPosts = text => async dispatch => {
    const response = await discogs.get(`/database/search?q=${text}&type=artist`);
  
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_POSTS, payload: response.data.results });
    history.push(`/results/${text}`);
  };